# Is it possible to use user-scalable=yes for only a particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to allow `user-scalable=yes` for a particular `<div>`. So, I need to know whether is possible and also is it feasible?. Is there is any plugin available to perform this?

Comment: Which kind of "plugin" do you refer to? And what does this has to do with jQuery or Javascript? Please specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to perform zoom in and zoom out functionality for a particular element alone.for example a div with id "target".I need to zoom in and zoom out in mobile for this  "target" alone.I need that in production so i am asked suggestion to use any plugins available for this purpose.

Comment: Than please, add this information to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for your question, no. But there's another way. Read on.

If you want to resize a `<div>` alone, you may use jQuery and use drag and drop for touch events. The `user-scalable=yes` is a page level attribute for mobile devices.

If you wanna use Pinch and Zoom, you can use [Pinch and zoom gestures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Pinch_zoom_gestures).

Comment: Thanks.I will take a look.

Comment: i have a doubt.How we can use the example mentioned in the that page to zoom in and zoom out the content present only in that target div.Can we use zoom css property to achieve this

Comment: @Vishnu The `zoom` CSS property is invalid and it's something totally different da.

Comment: then what i need to do to achieve pinch zoom for the particular element?

Comment: @Vishnu Dei, did you even see the link I gave? `:O`

Comment: yes bro i saw that link they are find the gesture for pinch zoom in and zoom out